# Debug Amazon Serverless Offline with Pycharm

Tags: pycharm, serverless-framework, serverless-offline

I use pycharm and wanted to know if there is a way to debug Amazon Serverless Offline with it. I found [this guide](https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-offline#debug-process), but though it gives some knowledge on how to interactively debug using an IDE it didn't help me. It also provides a detailed guide on how to debug using VSCODE, which I successfully implemented.

Answer (score 1):

Based in the guide's instructions for vscode, I was able to "migrate" that configuration to pycharm and had success in debugging with it.

I am new to the nodejs world, so my first insight was to realize that the command being used is actually npm.

This is my working configuration:

[image: working configuration]

Additional notes:

1. As you can see, I use [NVM](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) to easily change between node versions, but this is not necessary and pycharm will suggest your global Node version as default.
2. I also use yarn instead of npm, but if you use the later, then pycharm will suggest it as default.
3. You also need to add the "debug" script to your package.json, as explained in the guide:
   [image: "debug" script]